# Nvidia Nsight 2.2 OpenGL shader debugger - not working?

Tags: debugging, opengl, shader, nsight

I've got NVidia's Parallel Nsight 2.2 system configured on my two computers.  The target has a Geforce 450 gts with driver ver 301.42 and the host a Quadro 1000M with the same driver version.  Loading the simplest OpenGL 3.0 program (display a colored triangle using shaders) runs fine but I can't seem to get the Nsight shader debugger to work.

Everything seems to work, I can open the NSight->Windows->Shaders List window, double click a shader, have the source code open and select a line and set a breakpoint.  A big fat red dot shows up to indicate the break point is set, but the breakpoint is NEVER hit, so I'm stuck.

Has anyone ever got the OpenGL shader debugger working with Parallel Nsight 2.2?

B.t.w. the NSight->New Analysis Activity works great.  I can create a trace of all the openGL calls and view it with no problems.

Answer (score 1):

The OpenGL shader debugger requires a driver that is not released yet. You will need a driver more recent than 306.37 to get a good debugging experience.

-s